# how to print values of cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-cursor

I  am new to pl sql programming. I have the following cursor code.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cs_get_pricing(ca_ite_id VARCHAR2, ca_prg_id NUMBER) IS
    SELECT pri_ite_id,
           pri_prg_id,
           pri_price,
           pri_regular_price,
           pri_discount_period
    FROM   PRICE
    WHERE  pri_ite_id = ca_ite_id
    AND    pri_prg_id = ca_prg_id
    AND    TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN pri_startdt AND pri_enddt;

  rec_get_pricing    cs_get_pricing%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN cs_get_pricing('BTSTNDM203005', 700);

  FETCH cs_get_pricing  INTO  rec_get_pricing;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test');
  CLOSE cs_get_pricing;

  dbms_output.put_line(rec_get_pricing.pri_regular_price);
END;
```

This code gets compiles but it is not printing any values. I have checked the table , it has data for the aforementioned  values. how to print cursor values?

Comment: Which client are you using? In Oracle's own tools (SQL\*Plus, SQL Developer, SQLcl) you can `set serveroutput on` to see script output; GUI tools have other ways to display too.

Comment: Seems like you could test `dbms_output.put_line('test')` without any cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below and also refer this [link](https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-cursor-with-parameters/)

```
    DECLARE
        CURSOR cs_get_pricing(
          ca_ite_id VARCHAR2,
          ca_prg_id NUMBER) IS
          SELECT pri_ite_id,
                 pri_prg_id,
                 pri_price,
                 pri_regular_price,
                 pri_discount_period
          FROM   price
          WHERE  pri_ite_id = ca_ite_id
                 AND pri_prg_id = ca_prg_id
                 AND Trunc(SYSDATE) BETWEEN pri_startdt AND pri_enddt;
        rec_get_pricing cs_get_pricing%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
        OPEN cs_get_pricing('BTSTNDM203005', 700);
                LOOP 
        FETCH cs_get_pricing INTO rec_get_pricing;
                EXIT WHEN cs_get_pricing%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.Put_line('test');
        dbms_output.Put_line(rec_get_pricing.pri_regular_price);
        END LOOP;

        CLOSE cs_get_pricing;
    END;
```